# Extract number with percentage

Tags: python, regex

I have several texts from which I need to extract the number with a percentage, e.g., 1.4%, 2.5% and so on.

It is always one line within the whole text with the words 'management fee'. Issue is that sometimes it is 'management fee per year  3.5%' or 'management fee up to 2 years  2,5%' (the number can be with a dot or a comma).

So far I have

```
(?<=management fee\s)\d+([\,\.]\d+)?%
```

but this only works for the 'management fee 3.5%' and not for cases in which there are more words after management fee.

How can achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can match `management free and repeat optional words after it, as least as possible. Use a capturing group to get the value with the percentage sign.

You don't have to escape the `.` and the `,` in the character class.

If the whitespace char should be present before the number, you could use `\s+` to match 1+ more times.

```
\bmanagement fee(?:\s+\w+)*?\s*(-?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?%)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bg1cI3/1)

```
import re
 
regex = r"\bmanagement fee(?:\s+\w+)*?\s*(-?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?%)"
s = "management fee per year 3.5% or management fee up to 2 years 2,5%"
print(re.findall(regex, s))
 
# ['3.5%', '2,5%']
```

Comment: Well, did not notice your answer, and [came up](https://regex101.com/r/IhpZVM/2/) with `\bmanagement fee(?:\s+\w+)*?\s*(-?\d+(?:[.,]\d+)?%)`. [Python demo](https://ideone.com/sAd8q1). I think `(?: \w+)*` must be made non-greedy here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew At first I had made it non greedy, then I changed it to greedy :-) but I forgot to test it without the dot or comma. Thanks!

Comment: I will accept this as an answer as it covers a more general case, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
(?<=management fee.*)(\d+(?:[\,\.]\d+)?%)
```

result :
[image]

Comment: I believe this will be useful in simple cases, as the examples I wrote. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
(?<=management fee)?(\d[.,]\d%)
```

Note: This will have multiple matches.

Example: In the case of "management fee up to 1 year 2,5% and up to 2 years 3.5%" it will select both 2,5% and 3.5%

If you want the first match only then try disabling the global option.

If you want the last match try putting a $ after the expression

If you want strictly a single group to be matched let me know

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just focus on what you want, the percentage at the end of the line:

```
\d+[,.]\d+%$
```

If you need to match the beginning of the line to prevent false positives, match the first keyword and discard the text in between:

```
^"management".*(\d+[,.]\d+%)$
```

Comment: My fault here, I should have pointed out that there are more instances where a numbre with percentage can appear. In any case, your answer helps me with other extractions I might need to do.